# Mutex implementation for avoiding multiple instances downloading the application update at same time

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a multi-instance appalication there is application update function that downloads the update from internet and install it.
Now Problem is if there are multiple instances are open then thay all try to install update that leads to error. 
Simple  code Snippet I learnt after reading the tutorials.

```
    static bool IsSingleInstance()
    {
        try
        {
            // Try to open existing mutex.
            Mutex.OpenExisting("myMutex");

        }
        catch
        {
            // If exception occurred, there is no such mutex.
            Window1.mutex = new Mutex(true, "myMutex");

            // Only one instance.
            return true;
        }
        // More than one instance.
        return false;
    }
```

I am new at C#. So can anybody tell me that how to use Mutex to ensure that only one instance can download and install update.
please tell the links for appropriate tutorials if you know on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make the mutex global by

`Window1.mutex = new Mutex(true, "Global\\myMutex");`

`Mutex.OpenExisting("Global\\myMutex");`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing quite a few possible exceptions there, this example is much more appropriate at handling the various errors you may encounter, 
[Mutex.OpenExisting Method example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c41ybyt3.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is that you have a time gap between calls of `OpenExisting` and 'new Mutex`
so, i class that implements what you need may look like this.

```
class YourApp : IDisposable 
{
    private readonly Mutex _mutex;
    private bool _isFirstInstance;

    public YourApp()
    {
        _mutex = new Mutex(false, "myMutex");
    }

    ~YourApp()
    {
        this.Dispose(false);
        GC.SurpressFinalize(this);
    }

    public bool IsFirstInstance
    {
        if(_isFirstInstance)
            return true;

        _isFirstInstance = _mutex.WaitOne (TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1d), false);
        return _isFirstInstance;
    }

    private bool IsDisposed { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if(this.IsDisposed)
           return;

        if(disposing)
           _mutex.Dispose();

        this.IsDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

here is the reference i use for this answer: [Threading in C#: Mutex](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Mutex)